# Where does business logic fit in the Command Query Responsibility Segregation Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, cqrs

Suppose I have a method like this:

```
public int CalculateAge(DateTime birthDate)
```

Is this a Command?  Query?  Or should it be separated and not included as either a command or query?

It fits the query interface (`TOut Execute(TIn input`), but it's conceptually not a query, more of a mutator.

For a command we would need to set a variable in the command and expose it since typically commands don't return anything so that the caller could access the result.  So, I don't see a good fit there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example is not a mutator, command or query; it's simply a *function*.  You would need to know today's date to make the calculation, but calling that a query is stretching things a bit.

CQRS is an *architectural pattern.* In order for CQRS to be relevant, there needs to be something to query and command.  Typically, that would be a database, but it could be an embedded device like an Arduino, or whatever. CQRS simply separates the query functionality from the command functionality, using two separate API's.

In a multi-layer software architecture, CQRS lives in the Service Layer:

```
Database <--SQL--> DAL <--CRUD--> Service Layer <--Command-->  Client
                                              ^-----Query------^
```

Instead of Create, Read, Update and Delete methods that operate on individual entities, the Service Layer will expose methods like `TransferMoney` and `GetInvoice` (being examples of Command and Query, respectively).

**Further Reading**
[Command Query Responsibility Segregation by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)
[CQRS Example in C# at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568103.aspx)

Comment: So would I call that function as part of the query, or outside of it?  Let's say I get a widget from a database that has a birthdate.  I could set the age as part of the query, but that seems to violate single responsibility.   Should the query get the widget only and then pass my widget to a business component to run the business functions (like this) on it?

Comment: You're overthinking this.  Think of it this way: a Service Layer or Business Logic Layer translates business operations into CRUD calls for your database.  CQRS insures that query operations/information retrieval is separated from actions or commands.  That's it.

Comment: I'm just reading about CQRS pattern and for me it's simply like a service with logic driven by event/command handlers instead of some service class. You put logic in separate handler classes instead of service methods. I think this could be useful for modular architecture design, where you can have modules registering their own custom handlers reacting to some event from other core module. And it's also makes your application more event-driven.

Comment: Semantically concept of CQRS doesn't really fit into REST APIs where everything is based around nouns and not verbs and mostly focused on CRUD. That would mean creating commands for CRUD like CreateXCommand, UpdateXCommand, DeleteXCommand etc.

Comment: Maybe it wouldn't add that much complexity if you created generic commands for that. But still it's pretty much the same.

Answer (score 5):

```
public int CalculateAge(DateTime birthDate)
```

> Is this a Command? Query?

I would expect that to be a query -- it would be very surprising to find discover a method with that identifier on it has side effects.  The hint is that you don't need to change any data to calculate an answer here, you just need to *read* it.

You probably shouldn't think of it as a pure function though; "calculate age" implies that we are making a calculation of birthDate relative to some other reference point -- the state of the object serving the query, or the state of the system clock, or....  [Pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) don't include hidden state.

> The function result value cannot depend on any hidden information or state that may change while program execution proceeds or between different executions of the program

The "Query" terminology of CQRS comes from [Command Query Separation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html), an interface pattern introduced by Bertrand Meyer.  Martin Fowler offers this summary

> **Queries**: Return a result and do not change the observable state of the system (are free of side effects).

Greg Young, in introducing CQRS, just took the CQS pattern a step further: introducing the idea that the commands and queries could be separated into separate interfaces, and could therefore be implemented by distinct objects that share the same logical state (but not necessarily the same physical state).

Comment: I agree it fits the query interface, but it doesn't get data from a database or service, so I don't think "officially" it is a query.  I think the best approach keep this functions separate from command/query and run them independently.

Answer (score 3):

Recently come across this due to my own issues so I'll add my own $0.02. Since as others have pointed out this does not mutate the Aggregate Root (AR), it's not a Command and therefore should be handled on the query side.

My feeling is that the options are to do the calculation in:

1. The API (service layer) by querying the AR after (hydrating it)
2. The API (service layer) by querying the read models (aka query, view, dto, etc) and providing the result to the client on request
3. At the client side
4. Construct a new view model or property by subscribing to events (aka projection) and updating as the events come in
5. Some CQRS frameworks like [Cirqus](https://github.com/d60/Cirqus/wiki/Views) have the ability of query the AR (via the IViewContext) during the event handling stage on the view manager
6. Method or function on the Read model (if you're sharing the read model with the client - like Blazor)

We can eliminate (1) for Architectural reasons (not the correct use of the AR nor the API/Controllers). Eliminate (3) and also probably (6) also since BL should not be on the client.

(4) I'm sure the CQRS experts would go with this option, but it seems odd to do this for for dynamically calculated queries. And maybe impossible mathematically if the calculation relies on the current/final result (as your example does) and not individual events. Also you may need to subscribe/handle to many events with complexity more than just calculating via the AR)

IMO best two options are: (2) and (5) - is also architecturally frowned upon but since the AR is available/hydrated there already and is available there for special calculations I would probably go with (5) to update the read model